# Chrome apps executeScript issue

Tags: javascript, webview, google-chrome-app

I am trying to inject a script in my webview via the executeScript method. The script is successfully injected but I'd like the injected script to execute before any other scripts that are in that page. Is there any way to do that? I do the injection in the 'contentload' handler of the webview.
Thanks in advance.